# Method returning from one class to another class

Tags: java, oop, collections

I'm currently learning OOP in Java, I have tried to write a mini database system, everything works well but I have two methods which are located in class **CivilStatus** that are not working well and they keep giving me 0 as a return, the methods are `PersonAge(String NationalId)` and `CountSingle()`. I would be grateful if anyone would have solved this bug for me.

```
public class Person101 {
    String nationalIdString;
    String nameString;
    int Age;
    Boolean marriedBoolean;

    Person101(String newId, String name, Boolean newMarried) {
        nationalIdString = newId;
        nameString = name;
        marriedBoolean = newMarried;
        Age = 0;

    }

    public String getId() {

        return nationalIdString;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return nameString;
    }

    public int getAge() {

        return Age;
    }

    public Boolean getMarriedStatus() {

        return marriedBoolean;
    }

    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        Age = newAge;

    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        nameString = newName;

    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("The name is: " + nameString + " ,Id is: " + nationalIdString);

    }

    public boolean SingleJordanian() {
        if ((nationalIdString.contains("Jor")) && (marriedBoolean == false)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
public void birthday() {
        Age++;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CivilStatus1 {
    String nameString;
    ArrayList<Person101> personsArrayList;

    CivilStatus1(String newName) {
        nameString = newName;
        personsArrayList = new ArrayList<Person101>();

    }

    public String getName() {

        return nameString;
    }

    public ArrayList<Person101> getPerson101s() {

        return personsArrayList;
    }

    public int PersonAge(String NationalId) {
        int newAge = 0;
        for (Person101 person101 : personsArrayList) {
            if (person101.nationalIdString.equals(NationalId)) {
                newAge = person101.Age;

            } else {

            }
        }
        return newAge;

    }

    public int CountSingle() {
        int counter = 0;
        for (Person101 person101 : personsArrayList) {
            if (person101.SingleJordanian()) {
                counter = counter + 1;

            } else {

            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you fill `personsArrayList` anywhere? If not, that's the issue.

Comment: Unrelated: Do not save "Age". Save date of birth.

Comment: Do you know how to debug? The one who understands your code best is you and writing some print statements (logging state of your app into console) might help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the same for both methods. Writing

```
personsArrayList = new ArrayList<Person101>();
```

creates an **ArrayList**, but it's empty, as you have not added any items to  it. Then, when you try looping over the ArrayList

```
for (Person101 person101 : personsArrayList) {
    if (person101.nationalIdString.equals(NationalId)) {
        newAge = person101.Age;

    } else {

    }
}
```

It doesn't even enter the loop, as there is nothing to loop over.

You should first add some items to the loop, for instance:

```
Person101 person1 = new Person101();
personsArrayList.add(person1);
```

As an aside, I would suggest that you shouldn't include the variable types in the name, e.g. **personsArrayList**, **marriedBoolean**. You already specified the type when you declared it

```
ArrayList<Person101> personsArrayList;
```

Rather just name them persons, married etc.

Just my 2 cents :).

Comment: Thanks, but in which method should I declare and add my objects into the ArrayList?

Comment: I would recommend that you create a method in the CivilStatus1 class that takes a Person as an argument, for example addPerson(person), and call that method in another class.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be causing issues.

Firstly with the variables of each class it is better practice to specify if they are public

```java
public String nationalIdString;
public String nameString;
public int Age;
public Boolean marriedBoolean;
```

or private.

```java
private String nationalIdString;
private String nameString;
private int Age;
private Boolean marriedBoolean;
```

Otherwise the variables are package protected which may causing issues with accessing the variables.
If you set them to private you can access them using getter methods

```java
public String getNationalIdString(){
    return nationalIdString;
}
```

If you are using getters your method should look something like this

```java
    public int PersonAge(String NationalId) {
    int newAge = 0;
    for (Person101 person101 : personsArrayList) {
        if (person101.getNationalIdString().equals(NationalId)) {
            newAge = person101.getAge();

        } else {

        }
    }
    return newAge;

}
```

I'm not sure if this is causing the problem but it may be.
The other suggestion is using boolean instead of Boolean unless there is a specific reason why you are using it.

To help debug your code I suggest doing something like this

```java
    public int PersonAge(String NationalId) {
    int newAge = 0;
    for (Person101 person101 : personsArrayList) {
        System.out.println("Looking for: " + NationalID + " current person: " + person101.NationalID);
        if (person101.nationalIdString.equals(NationalId)) {
            newAge = person101.Age;
        }
    }
    return newAge;

}
```

This should help you locate the problem, you can also add the person's name so you can compare that to the data you inputted. I also removed the else branch of the if statement as it was not used.

Also check that `SingleJordanian()` is working as expected as that may be root of `CountSingle()` not working as intended.